# If you know 2 sides of the triangle, wha is the third side?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

I understand why A & C are correct but I don't get how E is a possible length since whatever number I plug in for x I get a number greater than 5x+5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2x + 17 < 5x + 5 \iff 12 < 3x \iff x > 4$. The question asks when this *could* be a possible answer, which it could (if $x > 4$).

Note how the other answers are never possible ($x+2$ will never be greater than $x+3$, $5x+6$ will never be smaller than $5x+5$ for positive $x$)

Comment: Small arithmetic errors.  Think you got a bit ahead of yourself.  Still a good answer.

Comment: @Mike This is rather embarassing. In my defense, speed is crucial in answering these questions :P